# Django model looping relationship

Tags: django, django-models

i have a problem for django model. i have location, machine, and part item.

- One location has many Machine.
- Every machine has many part Item.
- Different machine can has same part item.
- Part item has default file/document/photo. Every machine that use
  part item has own part item file/document/photo.
- Part item has default maintenance procedure, but for Certain machine,
  maintenance procedure for part Item can be different with the default
  or same as the default.

```
class location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descirption = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.ForeignKey(location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='machine')

class partitem(models.Model):
    itemNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descirption = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='machine')
    procedureDefault = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attachmentDefault = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

how do i define the attachment and procedure of part item if it different from default for certain machine?

```
procedureForEachMachine = models.CharField(max_length=255)
attachmentForEachMachine = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case for a [ManyToMany relationship with extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

This is because the attachment and the procedures are not `Partitem` attributes, but unique to each Machine x Partitem relationship (though, in most cases, it will assume a default value depending only on the Partitem).

It would be like something like this:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class PartItem(models.Model):
    machine = models.ManyToManyField(Machine, through='MachinePartItem')

class MachinePartItem(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    part_item = models.ForeignKey(PartItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    procedureDefault = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attachmentDefault = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```